# How to iterate tags inside webelement?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have html page like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>..</h3>
    <p>..<a>..</a>..</p>
    <p>..</p>
    <h4>..</h4>
</div>
```

I received webelement containing div tag.
And after this I want iterate tags inside

```
h3, p, p, h4
```

(I don't know which tags exactly will be in page)

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(but there I need specify tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = conteiner.find_elements_by_xpath("""/div/*""")
for item in items:
   print(item.tag_name)
   print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```